# How to read the Hammerfight end of level screen?

Tags: hammerfight

I finally beat the first hard branch of the game. I unlocked a few titles ("BP THE WINDBAG"), a weapon suspiciously similar to, but not totally unlike what I already had, and this level summary.

[image]

So, uh, I earned 10 crosses, 0 fame, 115 points, a overall rating of blue ribbon (???) and 280 glory. Color me pretty confused.

How can I read this screen? What does each field mean? How is each meter important?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keep in mind that most of what you see in the result screen is simply a summary of things that happen throughout the level (the action can get a little hectic though, so it's easy to miss the various prompts).

The section immediately under "RESULTS", where you have a bunch of crosses, is a summary of all the enemies you defeated. Crossed bones mean a dead beast/animal. There are other icons for defeating mechanical enemies (cogs, if I remember correctly) and subduing/killing a human enemy (a star and skull, respectively). The icons are actually identical to the kill prompts you get while playing:

[image]

The fame you earned is just that, how much fame you earned during the level. Fame can be earned by doing "impressive things" while playing the level, and I'm pretty sure getting fame is easier if you have a crowd watching you, like you do on some of the levels. When you do something impressive while playing, you should notice yellow/red smiley faces appear near your ship. The more/bigger the they are, the more impressive you were. Smashing hard into an enemy and shattering his armor is an example of something impressive you can do, and this will net you some yellow smileys. Red smileys represent you getting a bad reputation, such as when you kill an enemy who yielded.

Here's a shot of some serious glory gained for defeating an enemy:

[image]

And of a little less glory for simply hitting something hard (as indicated by the "Strong hit" icon just above it):

[image]

Next up, your "points scored" followed by a series of coins and tokens. This is simply a representation of the money you earned during the level (enemies hit usually drop coins. See the massive coin spill in the first of the glory screenshots, just under the smiley face. You have to run into them to pick them up, though).

The overall rating simply shows how well you did on the level, though unfortunately I have no idea what the thresholds for the ranks on any of the levels are. I can't even tell you how many ranks there are, or which token is better than the other.

Glory, I believe, can be considered the final score for the level (and eventually, the game). As far as I remember it adds up as you play.

Answer (score 5):

This screen is divided in multiples sections, which show you what you have done in the level.

First, the "crosses", show you the enemies you have beaten:

- A cross mean you killed  monster;
- A cog that you destroyed a machine;
- A skull that you killed a human;
- A star that a human surrendered.

You can have a combination of theses depending on what happened during the level.

Then, the fame section show you how much fame you gained during the level (obviously). You can fame by performing impressive moves (break a shield, disarm an adversary...) and lose some when you kill a human or hit a disarmed adversary.

The score section is simply how much money you gained. I think it's counted in copper coins, and show you exactly how much of each coins you got.

The overall rating is pretty obscure to me, it show you how well you did globally, but I'm not sure what are the ranks.

Finally, the glory part is your total score. I don't think it changes anything in the game, it is just some kind of high score.